# How do I get the highest value from a SharePoint list in SharePoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list of numbers in SharePoint, each number being a separate item. Eg.

1
5
3
2
7

I am running a SharePoint Designer workflow on a document set library, and in that workflow I need to pull up the highest value from this list of numbers (7 in this case). How do I pull the highest value from this list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should help, however, I don't know how easy it would be to query from a workflow?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265240/16162

Answer (score 0):

You could try: sort your list descending, then get the first item, that one will be the largest (this can be done in a view).